# Floated elements within floated elements

Tags: html, css

If I have the following layout

```
<div style='float: left;'>Outer Div </div>
<div style='float: left;'>
     <div style='float: left;'>Inner Div </div>
     <div style='float: left;'>Inner Div </div>
     <div style='float: left;'>Inner Div </div>
     <div style='float: left;'>Inner Div </div>
     <div style='float: left;'>Inner Div </div>
</div>
```

When resizing the browser first the second outer div will collapse under the first outer div. Only after that the inner divs will collapse. Is there a way to have the inner divs collapse first before the outer div collapses?

Answer (score 0):

That's sort of a weird situation.

To do what you're wanting, I think you need to go to responsive design `media` queries. Basically, you can give conditional CSS rules, say, based on the width of the browser window.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp